# Download to PDF not working

Tags: angular, pdf, download

I have the below code to download the JSON object from url. But the download is not happening.

```
     openDownloadWindow() {
    this.downloadPdf().subscribe(pdfBlob => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob);
        window.open(url);
    });
}
public downloadPdf() {
  const url =  'http://161.202.31.51:8185/sgdocsrv/ar/getARList';
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Authorization', 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token'));
  return this.http.get(url, {  headers: headers, responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob }).map(
      (res) => {
          return new Blob([res.blob()], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      });
}
```

Comment: Please provide us your backend code. Have you try to do someting like this ? `this.downloadPdf().subscribe(res => console.log(res));`

Comment: I have an array of json object which is displayed in my front end . I now want to download  all these contents to PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a bunch of things to change so here's what I had working :

```
public getMeMyPDF(): any {
    const url =  'http://161.202.31.51:8185/sgdocsrv/ar/getARList';
    this.PDF = this.http.get(url, {
      observe: 'response',
      headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type', 'application/pdf', 'Authorization',
      'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token')}),
      responseType: 'text' as 'text' // <-- this part is rediculous but necessary
    }).catch(this.handleError);
    return this.PDF;
}
```

I personally had it in a post request but get is obviously the more common and obvious scenario.

I finally stumbled upon this in a long github issue on angular.

the double trick was to have a cast from text to text and to have your whole options inside the http call as dirty as that may look.

I also threw in my syntax where I first declared a var and returned that (not necessarily a waste of a line if suddenly you need to console log it again), and also added a catch which you can handle in a global catch function for all your APIs.

Don't forget to like, favorite and **subscribe** to your api, wherever you call it. (even if you don't do anything inside the subscribe (in your case you will))

here's what I did back in my component that calls my apiservice.getMeMyPDF :

```
getMeAPDF(){
    this.apiService.getMeMyPDF().subscribe(res => {
      if(res !== null && res !== undefined){
        this.saveToFileSystem(res.body);
      }
    }, (error) => console.log(error), () => {});
  }

  private saveToFileSystem(response) {
    const blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'text/pdf' });
    const d = new Date();
    saveAs(blob, 'WOWPDF_' + this._datepipe.transform(d, 'yyyyMMdd_HHmmss') + '.pdf');
  }
```

Comment: I am facing the below issue : Failed to compile.
Module parse failed: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|         this.PDF = this.http.get(url, {
|             observe: 'response',
|             headers: new http_2.HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': , 'application/pdf': , 'Authorization': ,
|                 'JWT ': +localStorage.getItem('id_token') }),
|             responseType: 'text' // <-- this part is rediculous but necessary

Comment: well you use `Headers` not `HttpHeaders` did you `import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';` ? also try with your own method `Headers` instead. Just keep hitting the code with a hammer until it works :D

Comment: also I'm not entirely sure your `localStorage.getItem('id_token')` can necessarily be called within that specific context you might have to initialize it as a var outside the http call? I personally didn't have Auth. I updated my answer a bit.

Comment: @Nancy so? is it working? mark me as answer if yes :)

Comment: Yes !! I have posted another question. Could you please post any replies? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50018124/download-pdf-is-not-rendering-the-complete-list-of-data-from-ngfor-using-html2ca

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new function that subscribes to your `downloadPdf` function and opens a link to the `blob`:

```
openDownloadWindow() {
    this.downloadPdf().subscribe(pdfBlob => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob);
        window.open(url);
    });
}
```

Comment: Do i need to call openDownloadWindow function from html ? And where should i mention the url from where i get the JSON object.?

Comment: @Nancy Just replace the call to `downloadPdf` to `openDownloadWindow`. If you want to specify a URL you can change the function signature of both `downloadPdf` and  `openDownloadWindow` to accept a `string` as a parameter.

Comment: I am getting error property downloadPdf doesnt exist

Comment: @Nancy you need to put the `openDownloadWindow` function in the same class as `downloadPdf`.

Comment: Okay I have modified my code I have posted to what you have mentioned. I am getting error in headers and responsecontentType

Comment: This code actually opens a new window, but I get error Failed to download PDF