# Download PDF is not rendering the complete list of data from ngFor using html2canvas

Tags: pdf, download, html2canvas

[image][image]I have the below code to download the elements in ngFor as a PDF  . My html is a array list of data information rendered using ngFor . I have a downloadPDF function written which accepts the id as a parameter and loops through the array list and has to save entire loop of array data as PDF when I click on the downloadPDF button. I am not s[image]ure why its saving only the first element from the array finalArList . I have attached the JSON response of finalArList  and also the pdf file for reference. Any help on this would be really helpful . I am posting this after lot many tries.enter image description here

```
downloadPDF() {
       html2canvas(document.getElementById('testDiv')).then(function(canvas) {
      const img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      const doc = new jsPDF();
      doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 5, 5);
      doc.save('testCanvas.pdf');
      });
    }


HTML:

     <div id="testDiv" *ngFor="let finalArList of finalArList">
                            <div>
                            <h3>
                              {{finalArList.dischargeDate}} </h3>
                            <div>
                              <div>
                                <div>
                                  <label>Case number:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                  <span>{{finalArList.caseNo}}</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                <div>
                                  <label>Patient:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                  <span>{{finalArList.patientName}}</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                <div>
                                  <label>Hospital:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                  <span>{{finalArList.instName}}</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                <div>
                                  <label>Payee:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                  <span></span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                <div>
                                  <label>Total Doctor Fee:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                  <span>{{finalArList.formattedTotalDrFee}}</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                <div>
                                  <label>To be Collected:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                  <span>{{finalArList.formattedDrFeeToCollect}}</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                <div>
                                  <label>Payor:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                  <span>{{finalArList.payor}}</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                <div>
                                  <label>Remarks:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                  <span>{{finalArList.remark}}</span>
                                </div>  
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                <div>
                                  Paid
                                  <span></span>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                  Unpaid
                                  <span>{{finalArList.formattedUnpaidAmounr}}</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>                          
                              <div>
                                <button>View Payment Details</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
    </div>

     <button type="button"(click)="downloadPDF()">Download in PDF</button>
```

When i do like this  html2canvas(document.getElementById('myTable')).then(function (canvas) {
     console.log('canvas', +canvas);
I am getting NaN.

However, if I hover on top of canvas I get a list of objects attached in screennshot for reference.

[image]

Comment: Any comments for my question?

Comment: Guys !! any solutions pls . I tried to change the id to classname , but i am facing typecast error.

Comment: Hi Again :) ! the question, as is, is far from providing enough information. Try to imagine, like us, that you know nothing about your project. now, do you understand your own question or know where the problem might be coming from? I don't, for instance, know what a full list of data would look like nor what an incomplete data set looks like. And we are talking about the data in the pdf, right? what about a console.log of the returned data from the API, is the data complete at least at this step or did the loss happen before?

Comment: @tatsu I have edited my question with response and more details.

Comment: in that `then(function(canvas) {` console.log `canvas` see what you get. and add it to your question.

Comment: @tatsu i have updated the question with canvas log

Comment: @tatsu any update?

Comment: well Not a number is because you put `+` don't put `+` you already have `,` plus you don't wanna add

Comment: Anyways I have attached the screen shot of canvas object. Could you pls check that one

Comment: does it have a `data`  child?